# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10150][10300][3.67.28] Invalid parameter: Unknown column name DeliverAge. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I have a query like :

```
eQuery.append(" SELECT").append(" SUM(CASE WHEN Emp.Age = '44' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DeliverAge")
```

I am trying to map it like this :

```
 event.get(i).setDeliveryAge(resultset.getInt("DeliverAge"));
```

I have getters and setters for the field.

I am using this dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>db2jcc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I believe there is something to do with the drivers, I tried modifying my db2URL as well by adding useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics as 2.

```
db2.URL=jdbc\:db2\://${DB2_SERVER}\:${DB2_PORT}/${DB2_DSN}\:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage\=true\:allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet\=1\:useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics\=2;
```

Comment: Db2 might fold your column label to uppercase, but the getter is using mixed case. Try using the getter with uppercase DELIVERAGE.

Comment: There is no space between `SELECT` and `SUM`. Get the full query text and use it in the `CALL ADMIN_CMD('DESCRIBE SELECT ...')` call. What's the output?

Comment: @mao it didn't work, still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry @MarkBarinstein ,that was a typo here..I edited the query.

Comment: @GKr297your db2 jdbc driver seems to be a special build. Please use db2jcc4.jar (Type 4)  and try with the latest build available from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads